# Hide disabled builds in Visual Studio Team Explorer

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, team-explorer

Is it possible to hide disabled builds in Team Explorer in Visual Studio?  I don't want to see these anymore.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope - if you don't want to see them then you will need to delete them.  As long as you keep the TFSBuild.proj file around it isn't too hard to bring them back again.

Comment: That's what I figured.  They're in source control anyway, so we can restore it. Thanks!