# How do I hide/remove old builds in Team Build 2012 (TFS)

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild

I have an old build that I dont want to see anymore here in TFS2012.

[image]

What are the steps I need to take to get rid of it.

I see a similar question back in 2009 [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1494616/hide-disabled-builds-in-visual-studio-team-explorer), but I think the answer is no longer relevant in TFS2012... but if it is, what is the step by step process I need to follow.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can delete the build definition altogether if you wish.

1. Delete the builds associated to the definition
2. Delete the build definition

You can hide the build definition from your users, if you wish to keep the definition but remove it from sight (admins will still be stuck looking at it, but not your users):

1. Right-click on the build definition
2. Choose Security
3. Alter the groups that have permission to see this definition in the security page

You can 'back up' the build definition first if you wish by serializing it to XML first. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/21088619/895739.

Comment: ahh, I see what I was doing wrong.  In your two step process at the top, I was getting stuck at step 1.  I was deleting the builds (and logs) from windows explorer... but it still said I couldnt delete the build because I still had builds... I should have deleted them using Visual Studio like this:

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/ab6aafd5-c507-444e-a2fe-7fbedad77345/cannot-be-deleted-because-builds-still-exist-for-this-definition-wrong?forum=tfsbuild